# How to add levels in nested object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to add levels in dynamic nested object. For example

```js
[{
    "_id": "5a8855df9a8bb60e749c9d87",
    "name": "Test3",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a8856569a8bb60e749c9d88",
    "name": "Test4",
    "children": [{
      "_id": "5a885f6cf12a351f5465d2ad",
      "name": "Subtest4",
      "children": [{
        "_id": "5a88ab0d11650a1a0c0454ea",
        "name": "Sub45",
        "children": []
      }]
    }]
  },
]
```

I want to add levels in this nested object like this:

```js
{
  "_id": "5a8856569a8bb60e749c9d88",
  "name": "Test4",
  level: 1,
  "children": [{
    "_id": "5a885f6cf12a351f5465d2ad",
    "name": "Subtest4",
    level: 2 "children": [{
      "_id": "5a88ab0d11650a1a0c0454ea",
      "name": "Sub45",
      level: 3 "children": []
    }]
  }]
},
```

This is list is created dynamically and I want to add '-' depending on its level. If the level is 1 only add 1 '-'

Expected output is

```
Test3
Test4
-Subtest4
--Sub45
```

This is what I am doing

```
function tree(list,level) {

    _.each(list,e => {
        $('#parent').append(`<option value='${e._id}'>${e.name}</option>`)
        if(e.children.length) tree(e.children,++level);
    });        
}
```

Comment: Why is `Test3` not in your expected result, and to what do `sub1`, `sub2`and `subsub` refer (they don't appear in the input). Could you please make your example consistent throughout? You also mention 3 kinds of output: a nested object with level properties, a string with hyphens, and option elements. Which of those three is the real output you need?

Comment: End objective is to add dashes before names but if i able to add levels in object then adding '-' won't be problem.

Comment: It looks like you need to put *level* number of dashes in front of e.name, Array(level + 1).join("-") should create the dash string.  However you will have a problem passing `++level` into the recursive call, that will have to change to `level + 1`

Comment: Finding the level is something answered at [Traversing a tree and get the depth of every object](//stackoverflow.com/q/41343755) and [How to find depth of nodes in a nested json file?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38046665)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong `++level` because you're adding +1 in the same level, change to `level + 1`

*This approach uses `$.each` from `jQuery` to loop over an array.*

```js
var array = [{    "_id": "5a8855df9a8bb60e749c9d87",    "name": "Test3",    "children": []  },  {    "_id": "5a8856569a8bb60e749c9d88",    "name": "Test4",    "children": [{      "_id": "5a885f6cf12a351f5465d2ad",      "name": "Subtest4",      "children": [{        "_id": "5a88ab0d11650a1a0c0454ea",        "name": "Sub45",        "children": []      }]    }]  },];

function tree(list, level, dashes) {
  $.each(list, function() {
    $('#parent').append(`<option value='${this.id}'>${dashes}${this.name}</option>`)    
    if (this.children.length) tree(this.children, level + 1, `${dashes}-`);
  });
}

tree(array, 1, '');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='parent'>
</select>
```